# Unable to access UICollection view cell infromation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Hi I am trying to access UICollection view cell information through UIsegmentedcontrol.

In a collection view I have four labels and UIsegmented control.When I tap the segmented control, I want to display labels values.

here is my code.

```
- (UIView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.mySegmentedControl.tag = indexPath.row;
selectedSegment = cell.mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
[cell.mySegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
cell.caseid.text=[tmpDict objectForKey:@"CaseId"];
caseid = [tmpDict objectForKey:@"CaseId"];
}

- (void) segmentValueChanged: (UISegmentedControl *) sender {
//NSInteger index = sender.tag;
if(sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
{
 NSString *localcaseid = caseid; // it shows default value may be first cell value.
CollectionViewCell * cell = [[CollectionViewCell alloc]init];
NSString *localcaseid = cell.caseid.text; //it prints null value
}
else
{
}
```

The above code not works for me.any help will be appreciated.I want to display information for that particular cell.

Comment: Are you getting controller inside segmentValueChanged() method ?

Comment: no.............

Comment: the base problem is that, you do not keep track of the UICollectionViewCell instance. When you create a new instance of `UICollectionViewCell`, the caseid will not be the one, you expect it. The problem can be resolved, if you create a custom delegate, and pass the cell as parameter in it too. If you need further help, let me know.

Comment: Yes, I need help.can u explain briefly or can u show some example?

Comment: i will prepare an example.

Comment: can you check if mySegmentedControl is not nil

Comment: yes I checked.It is not nil.

Comment: Can you give me your project? So I can solve it, If you dont mind

Comment: sure..How Can I share my project

Comment: modijecky@gmail.com Send it

Comment: @MuthuRaj Did you send it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if(sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        NSString *localcaseid = caseid;
        NSIndexPath *tempIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];
        CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell *)[CollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:tempIndexPath];
        NSString *localcaseid = cell.caseid.text;
        NSLog(@"%@",localcaseid);
    }
    else {
    }
```

Comment: CollectionViewCell *cell = [self.myCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:tempIndexPath]; I tried like this.It shows incompatible pointer

Comment: It prints for first cell only.

Comment: incompatible pointer warring also remove, Check it and Let me know it is working or not.

Comment: @MuthuRaj it's my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

```
// CustomCell.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol CollectionViewCellDelegate;

@interface CustomCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property(weak, nonatomic) id<CollectionViewCellDelegate> delegate;

@end

// CustomCell.m

#import "CollectionViewCell.h"

// Create your delegate
@protocol CollectionViewCellDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)collectionViewCell:(CustomCollectionViewCell *)cell segmentedControlChangedValue:(UISegmentedControl *)control;
@end

@implementation CustomCollectionViewCell

// Implement this delegate call on the cell, not on the viewController
- (void) segmentValueChanged: (UISegmentedControl *) sender {
    // Call your delegate with the cell added as parameter
    [self.delegate collectionViewCell:self segmentedControlChangedValue:sender];
}

@end
```

In your viewcontroller, make sure it is confirming to the delegate, add `<CollectionViewCellDelegate>` next to your viewController declaration and import the cells header file.

// ViewController.h

```
#import "CustomCollectionViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CollectionViewCellDelegate>
```

// ViewController.m

// Assign the delegate in cellForItem to you VC

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // create your cell
    // assign your cell's delegate to self
    cell.delegate = self
}

    // Declare the delegate method on the viewController
    - (void)collectionViewCell:(CustomCollectionViewCell *)cell segmentedControlChangedValue:(UISegmentedControl *)control {
        // here you now have access to the cell, where the segmented was pressed in
        // Do what you need to and make sure you reload the data at the end of this function, when you have set up your cell

        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }
```